# Automatically include a JSP in every JSP

Tags: java, jsp, websphere

I would like to simplify my JSP's even further by transparently including them.  For instance, this is the line I would like to remove:

```
<%@ include file="/jsp/common/include.jsp"%>
```

The include.jsp file basically declares all the tag libraries I am using.  I am running this on WebSphere 6.0.2 I believe and have already tried this configuration:

```
<!--    Include this for every JSP page so we can strip an extra line from the JSP  -->
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
            <!--<include-prelude>/jsp/common/include.jsp</include-prelude>-->
            <include-coda>/jsp/common/include.jsp</include-coda>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
```

Both the `include-prelude` and `include-coda` did not work.

I was reading that other WebSphere users were not able to get this up and running; however, tomcat users were able to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `jsp-property-group` was introduced in JSP 2.0 (i.o.w. Servlet 2.4). Websphere 6.0 is Servlet 2.3.

So you have 3 options:

1. Forget it.
2. Upgrade Websphere.
3. Replace Websphere.

Comment: We might be upgrading websphere, but we will never replace it for the same reason it was chosen to develop on in the first place.  I used to like IBM products until I started using WID/WAS.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure which version of the Servlet spec this was introduced... is it possible that Websphere's servlet container doesn't support it?

Either way, for this sort of task there's a much nicer 3rd-party tool called [SiteMesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/). It allows you to compose pages in exactly the sort of way you describe, but in a very flexible way. Recommended.

Comment: I second this.  Either SiteMesh or Tiles.

Comment: I've used SiteMesh before and like it; however, we're using Tiles.  I wanted to just simplify the JSP so it was fewer lines of code, striped down to the meaningful part.

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing a Filter that calls

```
getRequestDispatch( "path-to-jsp-to-include" ).include( req, res )
```